# MacBook Pro Retina Boot Camp GeForce 337.88 Driver

Tags: bootcamp, macbook-pro, windows, graphics, driver

I have a 15" MacBook Pro Retina, Late 2013 (GeForce GT 750M) and while running Boot Camp 5.1 in Windows 7. The NVIDIA GeForce Experience taskbar icon asked me to download and install:

[GeForce 337.88 Driver](http://www.geforce.com/drivers/results/75992/nvidiaupdate#)

Is it OK to install this driver, or should I just stick with what's installed in the Boot Camp 5.1 drivers?

Comment: the decision is based on WHO asked you to install a driver?

Comment: It was the NVIDIA GeForce Experience taskbar icon. I updated my answer to make that clearer. Thanks.